# Как создать запрос в android studio для SQLite на обновление значение в строке

Tags: java, android, sqlite, запрос

Прошу помощи у джедаев по SQLite!
Есть таблица в которой есть наименование товара,категория,описание, количество.

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("create table "+ DirectTable.NAME + "("+
"_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        DirectTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
        DirectTable.Cols.DIRECTORY + ", " +
        DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT + ", " +
        DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION + ", " +
        DirectTable.Cols.QTY + ")"
);
```

есть методы добавить строку и вывести строки, а вот как обновить?

```
public void add_direct(Direct d) {
    //      mDirects.add(d);
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(d);
    mDatabase.insert(DirectTable.NAME, null, values);
} 

public List<Direct> getDirects() {
    //return mDirects;
    List<Direct> directs = new ArrayList<>();
    DirectCursorWrapper cursor = queryDirects(null, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            directs.add(cursor.getDirect());
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return directs;
}
```

Требуется что бы при добавлении пользователем этих данных происходила проверка на существование таких данных, в случае true, просто обновить колонку количество(сумма нового и старого значения), без добавления новой строки.
Ибо пока так:

```
mAdd = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DirectLab.get(getActivity()).add_direct(mDirect);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.add_direct, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mAdd.setEnabled(false);

        }
```

Comment: db.insertWithOnConflict(DirectTable.NAME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE), если вставка вызывает ошибку, обновит данные. То что нужно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798527/7566397

Comment: Причем здесь Android Studio? Людей, которые не видят разницы между Android и средством разработки Android Studio - надо беспощадно минусовать

Comment: @Barmaley, людей которые не отвечают по существу, ту да же... а если хочется высказать свое "фи", для этого есть функция "предложить правку "

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, может заодно подскажите как в запросе записать where по двум и более столбцам в cursor.query(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

Comment: Ошибаетесь, если хотите сказать "фи" - существует *минус* - почитайте [правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), править можно и нужно - я поправил метки

Comment: @Barmaley, ок, каюсь... Вы как гуру, можете подсказать нубу, как в запросе записать where по двум и более столбцам в cursor.query(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs), т.к. свой вариант считаю костыльным :                                                              DirectCursorWrapper c = queryDirects(DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION + "= ?", new String[]{description});
        DirectCursorWrapper c2 = queryDirects(DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT + "= ?", new String[]{product});

        if (c.moveToFirst() && c2.moveToFirst()) {}

Comment: 1 пост - 1 вопрос, выставьте другой вопрос, ответим

Comment: @Barmaley, не хотел плодить, ок...

Comment: кстати, обновите сами вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

Для обновления записей существует конструкция `update`

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Directory","Dir");
cv.put("Product","Book");
mDatabase.update(DirectTable.NAME, cv, "UUID="+uuid, null); //обновляем запись с конкретным uuid
```